# Unable to find base address or exported function of dynamically loaded library

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, frida

I'm able to detect when the library is loaded using System.loadLibrary, but Module.findBaseAddress returns null and Module.enumerateExports doesn't return anything.

Here's my code:

```
function processJniOnLoad(libraryName) {
    const funcSym = "JNI_OnLoad";
    const funcPtr = Module.findExportByName(libraryName, funcSym);

    const membase = Module.findBaseAddress(libraryName);
    console.log("Base address is " + membase);
    
    console.log("[+] Hooking " + funcSym + "() @ " + funcPtr + "...");

    Module.enumerateExports(libraryName, { onMatch: function(e) { console.log("type " + e.type + " name of function = " + e.name + " " + e.address); }, onComplete: function() { } });
}

function waitForLibLoading(libraryName) {
    var isLibLoaded = false;

    Interceptor.attach(Module.findExportByName(null, "android_dlopen_ext"), {
        onEnter: function (args) {
            var libraryPath = Memory.readCString(args[0]);
            if (libraryPath.includes(libraryName)) {
                console.log("[+] Loading library " + libraryPath + "...");
                isLibLoaded = true;
            }
        },
        onLeave: function (args) {
            if (isLibLoaded) {
                processJniOnLoad(libraryName);
                isLibLoaded = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

waitForLibLoading("library_name.so");
```

Output example:

```
C:\just_a_path>python peton3.py
[+] Loading library /data/app/com.app_name.app-<random string>==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/library_name.so...
Base address is null
[+] Hooking JNI_OnLoad() @ null...
```

Looking at the Exports tab in IDA, I can see that JNI_OnLoad is exported.

Comment: According to the Frida documentation `findExportByName` expects a moduleName as first parameter, not a filename. It may be possible that for your library the module name is different from the file-name. I would check the list of loaded modules via `Process.enumerateModules()`

Comment: Are you sure Python3 in Windows can handle Unix-style shared objects that contain plugins for Java?

Answer (score 0):

It because `JNI_OnLoad` has been called when you found `JNI_OnLoad`was exported with IDA.
You can try this method to HOOK `JNI_OnLoad` to analysis JNI_OnLoad behavior.
1.write a execute `dlopen` library_name.so get library handle
2.use `dlsym` get JNI_OnLoad symbol address
3.use inlinehook hook symbol address .
4.do whatever you want.